# is there a way to transition between functions in a class?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
tk = tk.Tk()
attackPhase = False
class player():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
    def changePhase(self,event):
        global attackPhase
        attackPhase = True
        print(attackPhase)
    def placeShip(self):
        self.master.bind("<Return>",self.changePhase)
    def attack(self,opponent):
        print('attack phase')

player1 = player(tk)
if not attackPhase:
    player1.placeShip()
else:
    player1.attack(ai)
tk.mainloop()
```

i was intending to press enter to change the value of attackPhase from False to True, thus running player1.attack(ai).

however, pressing enter only changes from False to True, but does not move to player1.attack(ai)

is there a way to transition between functions in classes?

Comment: You evaluate `attackPhase` exactly once, before you start the event loop.

Comment: Change to `self.attackPhase = not self.attackPhase` and place in `__init__`: `self.attackPhase = True`

Comment: you mean ```player1.attackPhase = not player1.attackPhase```?